# How to add selectpicker setting in a new select that added dynamically?

Tags: jquery, select

I am using bootstrap selectpicker and want to add a new selectpicker.

This is my selectpicker script:

```
$(document).on('focus',".selectpicker", function(){
    $(this).selectpicker({
        noneSelectedText : 'No Data',
        liveSearch       : true,
        maxOptions       : 1,
        size             : 12
    });
});
```

I want to target the new selectpicker but the above script is not working. because it is being added after the DOM.

This is my current script that add new selectpicker:

```
$('#btn_new_select').on('click', function(){

    //some text


    //$('.select2').selectpicker({                         
       //noneSelectedText : 'No Data',
       //liveSearch      : true,
       //maxOptions      : 1,
       //size            : 12
    //});
    //If I uncomment above script, the selectpicker is working. But, I do not want to rewrite this script.

    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');

});
```

Comment: wrap your code to document.(ready);

Comment: @HarsimranjitSingh well, it's already wrapped in document.(ready)